# Display Domain Name instead of IP for bucket content in google cloud platform?

Tags: load-balancing, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dns, google-cloud-cdn

I want to apply caching on my images by Google CDN so I created a bucket and then create load balancing and enable CDN.

**First:**
I have created a bucket. and upload some images. and give permission to the public.

```
gsms-bucket/images/image1.jpg 
gsms-bucket/images/image2.jpg
```

and so on...

https://storage.googleapis.com/gsms-bucket/images/image1.jpg

https://storage.googleapis.com/gsms-bucket/images/image2.jpg

**Second:**
create Load balancing and Enable CDN.

https://34.117.32.244/images/image1.jpg

https://34.117.32.244/images/image1.jpg

**Now My Question is...**
Is it possible to replace IP (34.117.32.244) with my domain (example.com) for accessing images?
IF I add New A Record it gives an error "A Record is already added".

https://example.com/images/image1.jpg

https://example.com/images/image1.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **name** of the bucket (as you create it) can be in a form of a domain name (domain ownership verification will be [required](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/domain-name-verification)).

If the bucket is to be accessed via LB+CDN - skip the above, you then create a load balancer and then point your dns A record to the LB's ip (in case of https you also [configure SSL](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates) for this domain by either uploading your certificate or opting to use Google Managed one).

Regarding the error you get - is it possible you already have an A record that you are trying to add?